# Why does intellisense not provide declared variables and "this" when using less than (<) in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

I have this code:

```
class Foo
{
    public void Baz()
    {
        int x = 0;
        var list = new List<int>();

        while (list.Count < ) // start right after "<"
    }
}
```

If I type `x` or `this` right after `<` as indicated, intellisense does not show me either of them, in fact it's really difficult to get it to let me use them because it is determined to force me to use whatever suggestion it *does* have:

[image]
[image]

If I use `<=` instead of `<` it works as expected:

[image]
[image]

It even works for `>` just not `<`.  What am I missing??

Comment: I wonder whether the "start generic syntax" ambiguity is a factor, but ultimately: this is a question that only the VS language service folks can answer. Perhaps log it as feedback via the menu item?

Comment: For me (in Visual Studio Professional 2019) it works as expected for both `x` and `this`, which indicates to me that this is just a Visual Studio 2022 issue. Maybe just an oversight? Strange.

Comment: @MarcGravell Oh great thinking.  That's probably it.  I'll open a feedback.

Comment: Maybe you can share the link of feedback here. It will help other people with similar problem.

Comment: Here it is: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Intellisense-thinks-Im-trying-to-start/10239675/

Comment: I've noticed that much of these situations occur because of fights over Intellisense and ReSharper. I often hit ESC like mad during some of these fights.